# How do I get resx files to work with Xamarin.iOS for localization

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios, resources

I'm trying to get resource files to work in Xamarin.iOS from VS2012. Basically I've created a separate project (PCL), named xxxx.Localization, with two .resx files in it - Strings.resx and Strings.da-DK.resx. In both of them I have a string named String1 with localized version of 'Hello'. The project generates two dll's - xxxx.Localization.dll and da-DK\xxxx.Localization.resources.dll. The problem is that only the xxxx.Localization.dll is added to the final xxxx.app and then only the default language is available. How do I get da-DK\xxxx.Localization.resources.dll (and other languages) to be added to the app? Or is there any other way to do cross platform localization, that works?

Comment: Here´s a solution at PCL level (meaning it works for ios, android, uwp, etc) with .txt files rather than resx: http://xleon.net/xamarin/dotnet/localization/i18n/2017/02/09/easy-and-cross-platform-localization-for-xamarin-and-dotnet/