# Is it possible to use RESX files defined PCL in Xamarin iOS/Android for multi-language support?

Tags: c#, xamarin, multilingual, resx

I am working on Xamarin iOS/Android and also have PCL project for portable class library.
What I need is to use RESX files of PCL projects in Xamarin iOS/Android.
My project is not Xamarin.Forms, so this link doesn't work for me.
[Localizing Xamarin.Forms Apps with RESX Resource Files][1]

I don't want to use separated files on iOS and android for multi-language support.

My idea is as following:

1) Create two RESX files for english and chinese in PCL project.

### AppResources.resx

### AppResources.zh-CN.resx

2) Load RESX files from iOS and Android projects.

3) When the language is swichted in my app, change UI languages.

But I cannot find the exact way.
I will be happy if you can help me.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

Comment: Making `AppResources` class in `AppResources.Designer.cs` public and then use reference of this file eg. MyProject.Localization.AppResources.StringKey will give you value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
Maybe this post helps me.
[ios localizing .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569392/xamarin-ios-localization-using-net)

I have created 2 resx files in PCL project.
and named it as following.

LackPack.resx

LangPack_zh_CN.resx

---

And I defined a static function in PCL to

```
    public static string GetString (I18N sID)
    {
        string sResource = STRINGS_ROOT + "_" + currLocale;
        Type type = Type.GetType (sResource);
        if (type == null) {
            if (currLocale.Length > 2) {
                sResource = STRINGS_ROOT + "_" + currLocale.Substring (0, 2); // Use first two letters of region code
                type = Type.GetType (sResource);
            }
        }
        if (type == null) {
            sResource = STRINGS_ROOT;
            type = Type.GetType (sResource);
            if (type == null) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("No strings resource file when looking for " + sID + " in " + currLocale);
                return null; // This shouldn't ever happen in theory
            }
        }
        ResourceManager resman = new ResourceManager (type);
        return resman.GetString (sID.ToString());
    }
```

we can use it on iOS/Android lie this.

```
Localise.GetString (I18N.TitleHistory);
public enum I18N
{
    BtnOk,
    BtnContinue,
    BtnLogin,
}
```

Comment: Here is an alternative solution using .txt files and a nuget ready to go: http://xleon.net/xamarin/dotnet/localization/i18n/2017/02/09/easy-and-cross-platform-localization-for-xamarin-and-dotnet/